# Declaring data in Vue with components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

According to [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers), this is how you declare data in Vue:

```
data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
}
```

However, when I do that it doesn't work and an error shows in the console:

```
The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

I change it to the following and then it works fine:

```
data() {
    return {
        name: 'Vue.js',
    }
}
```

Why do the Vue docs show the top bit of code when it doesn't work? Is there something wrong on my end?

**Edit:** This only happens when using components.

Comment: Error in the docs I guess ....

Answer (score 1):

In a root Vue instance (which is constructed via new Vue({ . . . }), you can simply use data: { . . . } without any problems.

When you are planing to reuse Vue components using Vue.component(...) or using "template" tag, Use data attribute as a function.

Please review the corresponding section of the Vue.js documentation for more information regarding this problem

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

You should declare data in Vue.js by doing

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', //This is the container in which Vue will be in. The #app means the id of the container is app
  data: {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to declare data in components different than when you set it on a `Vue` object.

> Instead, a component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object:

More: [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)